# numpy: calculate cross-covariance, without calculating the whole covariance matrix

Tags: numpy, covariance

The `numpy.cov(x, y)` with 1-d array inputs returns the entire 2x2 covariance matrix. Is there a way to calculate only the cross-covariance, i.e. `E[xy] - E[x]E[y]` without wasting time on calculating the two variances?

PS. How does one write equations on here? The $$ does not seem to work as it does on other Stack websites.

Comment: as for your PS question, you can either simply mark text you want as code and press the wavy brackets in the taskbar (these: {}) or use this character around your code: `

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with simply implementing the equation you wrote?

```py
# E[xy] - E[x]E[y]
cov = (x * y).mean() - x.mean() * y.mean()
```